# xcode - No rounded corners when Autolayout is turned OFF

Tags: ios, xcode

I tested an app on my device (iphone 4, iOS 5.1) but it gave me an error. Here on Stackoverflow I found that it is because autolayout in xcode 4.5 is turned on. The problem is that when I turned it off the rounded corners of the app disappeared. Is it a common behavior? And how can I set the rounded corners without Autolayout.

self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f; results in this:

[image]

and I'm looking for those slightly rounded corners for whole app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly confusing, but how about this?

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>    

self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
```

Comment: I have added some images so you can see what this does and what I'm actually looking for.